# django order_by() and distinct()

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to django, and I have been trying to use this below queryset to get my desired entries from my PGsql DB:

```
Books.all().filter(something=True).filter(other=True)\
            .order_by('-updated_at').distinct('title_of_book')
```

However, this does not seem to work (as I understand from the docs, distinct() and order_by() do not play nice with each other) - is there any other way (workaround) I can use to make this work?

Comment: You may use **raw** or even raw sql to achieve what you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it doesn't work?

Comment: I get `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` as a django error message.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to query, in plain English? It seems like "Get the most recent update of a book" but you left off the actual object the queryset isaganist. Can you add more details?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: When I wrote queryset.all() I meant Books.all() - I basically want to apply `distinct` to a field - which has been ordered by its `updated_time` Does this help?

Comment: Marginally, what exactly is the query you want though? Not using SQL commands, using plain language.

Comment: Could you also add the code of your Books model to the question?

Comment: When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order. See examples in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct
That explains the error. Still the questions remains what you really want to do.